Assets\Scripts\GameManager.cs(29,4): error CS8803: Top-level statements must precede namespace and type declarations. このエラーがでてくるのですが、分かる人いますか？
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    //変数の作成
    //スポナー
    //生成されたブロック格納

    Spawner spawner;//スポナー
    Block activeBlock;//生成されたブロック格納


    //スポナーオブジェクトをスポナー変数に格納するコードの記述

    private void Start()
    {
        spawner = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<Spawner>();
    
        //スポナークラスからブロック生成関数を呼んで変数に格納する
        if(!activeBlock)
        {
            activeBlock = spawner. SpawnBlock();
        }
    }
}
    private void Update()
    {
      if (activeBlock)
      {
          activeBlock.MoveDown();
      }
    }


おそらくエラーメッセージの(29,4)は29行目の4桁目を示しているでしょう。
0オリジンか1オリジンかで変わると思いますが、private void Update()の行頭のpか、その次の行の{の位置でしょうか。
その上の27行目の先頭に}があり、そのためpublic class GameManager : MonoBehaviourクラスが終了していて、private void Update(){...}がどのクラスにも属さない形で定義されており、質問のエラーが発生していると思われます。
27行目先頭の}を、private void Update(){...}定義の後(ファイルの末尾？)に移動してみましょう。
他には例えばこんな記事のソースコードと比較してみてください。
GameManager.cs - 個人で製作中のゲームにおいて意識している設計と実装
Unityでテトリスのサンプルプログラム GameManager.cs

CS8803 のエラーが表示されるのは「コンソール アプリ」なのにローカル関数 Update がclassの定義の後にあるからです。
Visual Studio で private void Update() にカーソルを置くとエラー内容が表示されます。
このプログラムは本当に「コンソール アプリ」なのでしょうか、実行する命令がないように見えます。
参考URL
コンパイラ エラー CS8803 - C# reference | Microsoft Learn
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs8803
C# コンソール アプリ テンプレートで最上位レベルのステートメントが生成される | Microsoft Learn
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates
以上
